# Find a button based on name

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to search MS Access (2016) for a button / combo box / etc on a form by the name of the button?

Is there a way to find where on a form a particular subroutine is used?

I have a sub that I cannot find where it is actually used within an Access DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form property sheet in Design View you can select any item from the drop-down list. If the name isn't in the list (easy enough to check as it's an alphabetical list), it's probably just old underlying code that has remained in the subroutine after being deleted from the form.

If you mean finding a button via code, you reference it via the form rather than the subroutine, using: `Forms!formName!buttonName`.

Comment: Thank you!  This answered my question.  My suspicion was correct, I have inherited old underlying code.